# Weird coloured circles around fluid sim

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation, mantaflow

I'm trying to create a fluid sim however whenever I view it in viewport the liquid is covered in these strange heatmap-like circles that wont go away. How do I get rid of them?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing the flip particles that make up your simulation.

You can disable them after baking.

1. Cache/Bake the simulation.
2. Turn off *Liquid* on the domain.
   [image]

Comment: thanks! glad it was just a simple fix.

Comment: The particles should not render anyways.